# from lowercase to uppercase: fatal errror

Tags: c

I get this error message for the following C program that is suppose to change one word in string to capital letters.

```
1>verkefni06.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strhlt referenced in function _main
1>c:\kit\skilaverk06\Debug\skilaverk06.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is the code I got so far with, any help resulting the code to work is very much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
pragma warning(disable : 4996)
pragma warning(disable : 4550)
/* strindex:  return index of t in s, -1 if none */



/* getline: get line into s, return length */

int getline (char s[], int lim)
{
   int c, i;

   i = 0;
    while (--lim > 0 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
      s[i++] = c;
   s[i] = '\0';
   return i;
}

 /* strindex: return index of t in s , -1 if none */
int strindex (char s[], char t[])
{
   int i, j, k;

   for (i=0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
      for (j=i, k=0; t[k] != '\0' && s [j]==t[k]; j++, k++)
         ;
      if (k > 0 && t[k] == '\0')
         return i;
    }
   return -1;
}


 int strhlt(char sz[], char szHigh[]); 

main()
{ 

   char sz [60];

   strcpy;

   getline (sz,60);
   getline (sz, 60);

   strhlt (sz,"write" ); 
   getline ("%s",60);


   printf("skrifadu stutta setningu (mest 60 stafabil): ");
   printf("\n\nRitadu ordid sem breytist i hastafi (mest 10 stafi): %s", sz);

   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getline ("%s",60);`  ??

Comment: Where is `strhlt` defined? It is not standard function.

Comment: And what are those pragmas for? You shouldn't hide the warnings without commenting why it was needed.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `strcpy;`?

Comment: And you should really use `int main(void)`, as it is standard form.

Comment: A good advice: When learning C, don't start with writing your own string functions. They just cause you headache and broken programs. Use the standard functions that exists, atleast until you can argue why you shouldn't use them.

Answer (score 1):

```
int strhlt(char sz[], char szHigh[]);
```

The linkage editor is looking for the definition of this function. It isn't in this file. Are you linking it from somewhere else??

If that's the case, you need an `extern`

```
extern int strhlt(char sz[], char szHigh[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no definition for `strhlt()` in your code and it is not a library function too.

only declaration is available.

```
int strhlt(char sz[], char szHigh[]);
```

so during linker time, you are getting this error.